# Непонятны отличия двух способов выделения памяти

Tags: c

Ребят, не могу понять в чем отличия двух способов выделения памяти, 1-ый способ мне кажется гораздо понятней. Почему во втором способе нужно использовать оператор структурного указателя(->), а в первом просто точку? -> используют когда нужно получить доступ к данным структуры на которую ссылается переменная указатель, получается тогда в первом способе тоже нужно использовать ->, а не точку. Объясните пожалуйста, совершенно не могу понять.

1 способ:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct BooksInfo
{
    char name[50];
    char author[50];
    int pages;
    int year;
};
int main (void)
{
    int ctr,quantily;
    puts("Сколько книг вы хотите заполнить? ");
    scanf (" %d", &quantily);
    getchar();
    struct BooksInfo *books;
 books=(struct BooksInfo*) malloc(quantily*sizeof(struct BooksInfo));
    for (ctr=0;ctr<quantily;ctr++)
    {
        puts ("Какое название у книги? ");
        scanf("%s",books[ctr].name);
        puts ("Какой автор книги? ");
        scanf("%s",books[ctr].author);
        puts ("Сколько страниц в книге? ");
        scanf("%d",&books[ctr].pages);
        puts ("Какого года книжка? ");
        scanf("%d",&books[ctr].year);
    }


    return 0 ;
}
```

2-ой способ:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct BooksInfo
{
    char name[50];
    char author[50];
    int pages;
    int year;
};
int main (void)
{
    int ctr,quantily;
    puts("Сколько книг вы хотите заполнить? ");
    scanf (" %d", &quantily);
    getchar();
    struct BooksInfo *books[quantily];
    for (ctr=0;ctr<quantily;ctr++)
    {
     books[ctr]=(struct BooksInfo*) malloc(sizeof(struct BooksInfo));
        puts ("Какое название у книги? ");
        scanf("%s",books[ctr]->name);
        puts ("Какой автор книги? ");
        scanf("%s",books[ctr]->author);
        puts ("Сколько страниц в книге? ");
        scanf("%d",&books[ctr]->pages);
        puts ("Какого года книжка? ");
        scanf("%d",&books[ctr]->year);
    }


    return 0 ;
}
```

И да, я знаю что нужно делать проверку выделения динамической памяти и очищать ее.

Я правильно понял как работают оба способа?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wa1t.png): [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я немного исправил код, а именно, убрал звёздочки при выделении памяти

Comment: Это не "два способа выделения памяти", а две совершено разные по своей сути структуры данных. Неудивительно, что для двух совершено разных структур данных память выделяется по-разному.

Comment: @AnT, то есть мне ответили неверно?

Comment: Вам все правильно ответили. Только суть вопроса требует уточнения. Одно дело, это когда речь идет о двух разных способах приготовить борщ. Другое дело - когда речь идет о борще и о рассольнике. У вас в вопросе как раз фигурирует борщ и рассольник. Совсем неудивительно, что готовятся они по-разному. А дальше уже у вас надо спрашивать, что же вы хотели получить: борщ или рассольник? Если вам просто хочется поесть, то вам может быть все равно, борщ получится или рассольник. А вот если вам нужен именно борщ, то - это это совсем другое  дело.

Comment: У вас в первом примере создается массив объектов `BooksInfo`. (Неправильно создается, кстати. Под `malloc` должно быть `quantily * sizeof(struct BooksInfo)`). А во втором случае у вас создается массив *указателей* на объекты `BooksInfo`. Так что же вам нужно то: массив объектов или массив указателей на объекты? Это только вам известно.

Comment: @AnT ,Но они ничем же не отличаются, что то работает, что другое. Я сейчас добавлю иллюстрацию того как я понял это все, а вы ответите правильно ли я понял? И кстати, почему звездочку(указатель) нужно убрать в 1 способе в функции malloc?

Comment: Работает одинаково я имел ввиду

Comment: `что то работает, что другое` — когда вы вылезаете за пределы одного буфера, то с высокой вероятностью влезаете в другой. В данной программе из-за её простоты это не страшно — она завершается раньше, чем повреждённый кусок будет кем-то прочитан. Но в долгоживущих программах это могут быть данные этой же программы или какой-то библиотеки. Ну а попутное перезатирание служебных заголовков приведёт к падении при возврате затронутого блока в кучу (через free, например).

Comment: `И кстати, почему звездочку(указатель) нужно убрать в 1 способе в функции malloc` — потому что в первом случае у вас массив непосредственно самих структур. И буфер, соответственно, надо выделять размером _количество элементов \* размер одного элемента-структуры_.

Comment: @ߚߤߘ  
Но в первом случае у меня же указатель на первый элемент массива структур? Или это не имеет значения?

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста на мою иллюстрацию(или блок-схему). Она правильно отображает два способа?

Comment: То есть в первом случае просто указатель на массив структур, а во втором -массив указателей на структуры, что по сути же аналогично первому способу(ведь это просто переменные указатели одного типа расположенные рядом в памяти, которые хранят адреса структур). Почему тогда  во втором случае нужно добавлять звездочку при вычислении памяти

Comment: ну вот смотрю я на две схемы- ничем же абсолютно не отличаются, ну уже два дня не могу понять

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнём с операций `.` и `->`. Операция обращения к элементу структуры `.` ставится между объектом структуры и именем поля: `str.field`. При работе с указателем на структуру обращение к полю следовало бы писать так: `(*str_ptr).field`, однако такой способ не очень понятен, а операция распространена. Поэтому сделали её синоним - операцию `->`: `str_ptr->field`.

Далее про выделение памяти. В двух примерах идёт работа с двумя разными областями памяти. Начнём со второго примера, где используется массив. Конструкции вида `int a[N]` обеспечивают место для массива в **стеке**. Стековая память - это память подо все временные объекты процедуры. Она выделяется автоматически при входе в процедуру и очищается автоматически при завершении процедуры. Но тут есть хитрость. В примере `N` является переменной, т.е. размер массива заранее неизвестен. Это случай массива переменной длинны (VLA), который был добавлен в стандарт C99. Для такого массива память выделяется не при входе в процедуру, а в точке объявления массива.

В первом случае используется процедура `malloc`, которая выделяет память в **куче**. Куча - область динамической памяти, которая контролируется только программистом. Поэтому после завершения процедуры память, выделенная через `malloc` будет жить и к ней можно обращаться. Для очистки такой памяти используется операция `free`.

Теперь перейдём к конкретным примерам. Рассмотрим первый пример:

```
books=(struct BooksInfo*) malloc(quantily*sizeof(struct BooksInfo*));
```

Здесь у нас выделяется участок памяти, содержащий `quantily` указателей на структуру `BooksInfo`. Судя по дальнейшему использованию этого участка памяти, на самом деле подразумевалась такая конструкция:

```
books=(struct BooksInfo*) malloc(quantily*sizeof(struct BooksInfo));
```

Теперь данный участок памяти содержит `quantily` объектов типа `BooksInfo`. При использовании операции доступа к элементу массива `[]` мы обращаемся к заданному внутри скобок элементу. Т.о. конструкция `books[ctr]` своим результатом будет иметь объект типа `BooksInfo`. Как мы уже знаем, для доступа к полям структур используется операция `.`, что и было сделано: `books[ctr].name`.

Теперь рассмотрим конструкцию

```
struct BooksInfo *books[quantily];
```

Здесь мы говорим что объект `books` является массивом указателей на структуру `BooksInfo`. Но нам нужно работать с объектами, поэтому в цикле мы выделяем память под для каждого указателя:

```
books[ctr]=(struct BooksInfo*) malloc(sizeof(struct BooksInfo*));
```

Теперь рассмотрим что будет результатом конструкции `books[ctr]`. Мы помним что в массиве лежат указатели на структуру, поэтому мы получим объект типа `BooksInfo *`. Чтобы обратиться к полю объекта, на который структура указывает, следует использовать операцию `->`.

**UPD**

Про исторические различия операций `(*).` и `->` можно почитать в этом [посте](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366083/why-does-the-arrow-operator-in-c-exist), спасибо @Croessmah за комментарий

Comment: Спасибо вам, почти понял)

Comment: struct BooksInfo * books;
 books=(struct BooksInfo*) malloc(quantily*sizeof(struct BooksInfo*));, а тут в первом примере разве books не указатель на структуру?

Comment: "Поэтому сделали её синоним - операцию ->" - не поэтому. Подробнее: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366083/why-does-the-arrow-operator-in-c-exist

Comment: @Croessmah В первом пример books же указатель на структуру?

Comment: @alexanius Что в первом случае books указатель на структуру, что и во втором, все равно не могу понять.

Comment: @Croessmah спасибо, интересный пост. В нём указывается на разницу поведения операций `.` и `->` в первых версиях языка, однако не приводится слов авторов языка по данному вопросу. В своём ответе я процитировал второе издание "Язык программирования C" от K&R, где они говорили что `->' введён для удобства.

Comment: @bylochka Нет, во втором `books` - массив указателей, а в первом - указатель на область памяти с последовательно идущими объектами. Поэтому при доступе к элементу в первом случае `books[i]` вернёт объект, а во втором - указатель на объект.

Comment: Ааааа, теперь более менее все встало на свои места, огромное вам спасибо ) Кстати, после того как допрочту книжку Грега Перри и дорешаю задачки в книжке "100 примеров на си", думаю купить книгу от K&R и ещё раз отшлифовать полученные знания. Или не стоит тратить время на чтении этой книги?

Comment: @bylochka Ну мне кажется, с этой книги следовало начинать :) Но если уж так сложилось, то возможно будет лучше где-нибудь через пол годика полистать её, повспоминать, вдруг глаз за что-то новое зацепится

Answer (score 3):

В первом случае выделяется один большой кусок памяти и в нем размещается весь массив объектов. Хороший, надежный способ. Удаление - один вызов `free`. Так как размещается массив структур, то и обращение к одному элементу - точка.

Во втором случае вначале создается массив указателей на структуры. Но при этом используется VLA. Но так как код сишный, то это ок. Потом для каждой структуры выделяется память. В геймдеве такое очень не любят - слишком много мелких объектов. Плюс код освобождения нужно аккуратно писать.

В втором случае в массиве хранятся указатели на структуры. Поэтому нужно использовать стрелочку. Либо явно разыменовывать через `*` и тогда можно будет использовать точку.

Comment: Вау, огромное вам спасибо за такой подробный ответ)) Теперь все понятно стало:)

Comment: подождите, но в первом способе books же тоже указатель на первую структуру

Comment: если я нарисую схему, иллюстрирующую то, как я понял ваш ответ, вы исправите меня если я что то понял неправильно?

Comment: Однако в выделении памяти в первом случае содержится грубая ошибка - размер памяти вычислен неправильно.